# AWS Lambda not connecting to external resources after certain number of executions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function written in python. The function is invoked when an entry is made to the DynamoDb table. The function gets invoked correctly, and indexes records from DynamoDB to elasticsearch.

However, after certain execution cycles of execution, the lambda starts timing out. It does not connect to Elasticsearch url, just times out.

Elasticsearch is hosted on Elastic cloud (cloud.elastic.co) and has a public url. I have a lambda security group that allows all inbound traffic.

Any idea how to fix these timeouts ?

Following is the trace from the cloudwatch logs:

```
[WARNING] 2017-02-03T02:44:36.228Z 2a34b9b2-5616-4de5-89dc-5e52e4e03412 HEAD https://elasticsearch-url:9243/ [status:N/A request:40.098s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 113, in perform_request
response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
File "/var/task/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/var/task/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 324, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "/var/task/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/var/task/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/var/task/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/var/task/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/var/task/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.timeout))
ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f22ac0fe310>, 'Connection to elasticsearch-url timed out. (connect timeout=10)')
```